# What technological/economic factors triggered the Industrial Revolution?

Tags: industrial-revolution

In the 19<sup>th</sup> century, many things started to change. The world of 1800 would not be a shock to a person from the 15<sup>th</sup> century. But for some reason, the world of today would be an incredible shock to someone from the 19<sup>th</sup> century. We have airplanes, automobiles, high speed trains. We've even put someone on the moon. All this happened in approximately 150 years, from the start of the Industrial Revolution until now. This is all fine and dandy, but *why* did the Industrial revolution start when it did? What happened?

Comment: You might choose to narrow this a little as this is a very broad question that can be answered in a variety of different ways. I've seen approaches/arguments range from political, economics, social, etc. Otherwise, great question!

Comment: In fact, there was a chain reaction with lots of different factors playing together - enough to fill a book or two with the answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Revolution#Causes

Comment: Sorry to quibble, but... a 15th century person would not be shocked by the world of 1800?  A New World across the ocean, people calling themselves Christians without acknowledging the Pope, France having recently been ruled by outspoken atheists?  He or she would most certainly be shocked.

Comment: @RoseAmes I mean technologically; those would be strange, but not as strange as finding out that there was someone on the moon, or that I can fly across the USA in a few hours.

Comment: Not sure it it's not the other way around: to us in the 21st century both the 15th and the 19th feel rather backward. But a 19th century person would have been exposed to industrialism, to scientific progress and to technological gadgets - so the 21st century would have felt to him as an awesome but still more of the same kind of thing. Whereas the 15th century person who was used to a static world in which new technologies seldom if ever appeared might well have been shocked at the 19th century.

Comment: Here is a well reasoned look at likely underlying causes of the *Great Divergence* between European and Asian cultures, starting in the 13th century: http://unenumerated.blogspot.ca/2013_11_01_archive.html. Note the 5 key factors listed: (a) heavy dairying; (b) co-evolution of human lactase persistence & cow milk proteins; (c) delayed marriage; (d) hay; and (e) greater use of draft animals (and their breeding for increased size)

Comment: Maybe you want to refine a little your title, as it is misleading: the Industrial Revolution took place in 18th,19th century, while your question seems more focusing on 20th century. These are two different era.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all started with a fairly simple change in the way that crops were managed and produced in England. In the late 1700's farmers began to realize that rather than leaving their fields fallow after a harvest, they could plant beans or other products that resulted in restoring the fertility of the soil. Then as they began to rotate their crops in different fields, the crop production began to increase. As crop production began to increase, the food supplies for the general population as well as livesock increased, so both began to increase. The sale of increasing numbers of livestock and volumes of crops resulted in the need for better routes of transportation, so water canals were developed and roads were improved. Eventually the railroad came along and helped spread these new growths in commerce.

Ultimately, each small change led to a new need which was then addressed by another change.  Sometimes it was as simple as rotating crops, and other times it involved the inventions of new equipment that could more efficiently harvest the crops or transport them once they were harvested. The successful increase in the volume of crops produced ultimately led to an increasing demand for better ways to process the crops.

As a result of this agricultural change, commerce within the country began to increase as well. Suddenly there were more people who were able to earn wages that allowed them to have disposable income. This resulted in the need for other goods to sell to this increasing working class, and that led to more improvements to help mass produce products, such as textiles. From there it just continued to snowball.

So, having said all that, the simple answer is that a simple discovery of a way to rotate crops to keep the soil more fertile started the whole thing rolling!

Comment: This sort of answers how the Agricultural Revolution came about (in Great Britain), which was indeed an important precursor to the Industrial Revolution, but far from it.

Comment: Interesting, I have seen it well argued that Britain's Industrial Revolution was largely due to Britain's excellent reserves of fossil fuels (especially charcoal) compared to other advanced European nations at the time (e.g. France, Germany, Italy).

Comment: Given that Mercantile Britain was importing corn before the corn laws—and that highly productive France did not experience an industrial revolution—this argument is unconvincing.

Comment: Good answer, although it doesn't explain how better yields lead to more people earning wages. That may be obvious to you and me, but I don't think it's obvious until you know. ;-)

Comment: Very good answer. Jethro Tull's agricultural revolution of the 1710s gets less credit than it deserves for setting up the industrial revolution of the 1780s.

Answer (score 7):

It's a classic question of why the industrial revolution happened when and where it did. And answers range to everything from "Good Cannon makers" to "Because the British drank tea!"

It's likely that the question is impossible to answer conclusively. But what I would like to do is to set up a number of prerequisites for an industrial revolution. It's not certain that an industrial revolution will happen when these prerequisites are met, but I do think they are required, and I also think the 18th century Britain is the first time in history where they all have been fulfilled at the same time.

**1. High agricultural yield, leading to cheap labour**

This is what Steven Drennon talks about in his answer. The British Agricultural revolution led to farms being able to produce more food and [feed more people](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/british/empire_seapower/agricultural_revolution_01.shtml). As a result, the population in cities increase, and there is a lot of labour available.

**2. Technological ability**

The ancient Greeks invented steam-powered toys. Why didn't they invent a steam engine? Because they didn't have the technology. The first attempts at steam engines in Britain and France failed, because the materials weren't up to the job of handling steam pressure. Also Watt could not have invented the condenser, and made the steam engine a much more economical alternative, unless he had understood boiling and condensing and how related to the different temperatures in the machine.

**3. A capitalist economic system**

In addition to a work force, you also need inventors who invent, industrialists who run things and investors that provide the money.

Point 1 and 2 in turn has a common prerequisite:

**4. A scientific method**

You can't get high crop yields if you think the most important part of the crop yield is praying to gods or making fertilizer by burying rams horns by the full moon. You will not learn the laws of thermodynamics if you think that converting water to steam is a form of magic.

And all of the above have a last prerequisite:

**Liberty**

**1.** and **3.** needs economic liberty; private ownership of land and other means of production, and the right to do what you think is best to make money and invest that money.

**2.** and **4.** needs liberty in ideology and thinking. The liberty to say that earth may not be in the centre of a theological universe, but zip around all by itself in a universe ruled by mechanics.

**3.** Also has a final prerequisite:

**5. A big trading network**

So there are people that can accumulate wealth that can be invested in industry.

There is also an argument that you need a good source of energy, ie coal. And that aragument is that late medieval and renaissance Netherlands had pretty much all of the liberty requirements fullfilled, but still did not get an agricultural revolution. But perhaps it was missing the natural resources needed. On the other hand I have also seen the argument that it simply was too early, the science and technology wasn't there yet, when the Netherlands had liberty and money.

Comment: I know there aren't many sources, but please point out what you think needs to be sourced, and I'll dig em up bit by bit.

Answer (score 4):

The knowledge necessary to build the machines that backed the industrial revolution (notably, steam engines) had been around for *quite* a while before that (ancient Greeks were fully aware of how to use steam to move things); but it had never been used widely for a variety of reasons:

- Slaves were available to work for free (or at a very small cost); so, why bother with engines at all?
- There was very little population compared to today, so there was no real need to grow a lot of food or mass-produce things.
- And, anyway, a lot of people were just too poor to buy anything; so why bother with mass production when only a few people were actually able to buy something?

In the short run, human labour is vastly cheaper than designing, building, running and mantaining machines, which instead leads to much greater efficiency in the long run. What actually started the whole thing were changing social and economic factors, which made an industrial economy worthwhile.

Comment: What social and economic factors?

Answer (score 2):

The industrial revolution occurred as a result of scientific advances in Europe. Specifically the Steam Engine and related Manufacturing Technology. However the Industrial Revolution began specifically in Britain, since wages in Britain were significantly higher than on the continent. This disparity increased the incentive for British businessmen (vs continental European) to invest in labor saving machines, which began the Industrial Revolution.

Unprecedented scientific advancements allowed economics to favor mechanization and spawn the Industrial Revolution.

Answer (score 0):

The Industrial Revolution was due in large part to the introduction of "engines," specifically the [steam engine,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_engine) and the [internal combustion engine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_internal_combustion_engine)

This allowed for the substitution of fuel as sources of energy (coal generated steam or steam engines, oil drove internal combustion engines) on a much larger scale than human or animal power. In essence, human beings were freed up to manage high-powered "engines" (and "machines" driven by engines) in factories, instead of having to put up a large part of the labor power on a much smaller scale.

Accompanying these changes was the development of banking, which allowed many "small" deposits to be combined into loans for the devlopment of factories and other large scale enterprises, to corporations that allowed people to invest in these enterprises with "limited liability."

This sequence is best represented by the industrialization branch of the game Civilization II, from steam engine, to railroads, industrialization, the corporation, (oil) refining, and (internal) combustion.

Comment: Wel... Larger scale than human and animal power was already in widespread use with windmills and watermills. In fact, the industrial revolution was already well underway when the steam engine became a practical solution to drive factories in the last decades if the 17th century. It definitely sped things up though, by allowing you to put factories anywhere.